# Flot Line graph: draw lines even if null in-between

Tags: graph, flot

I am drawing a line chart. Sometimes there is no value (null) for a certain time. I want to draw a line between two points even if there are null points in-between

example:

['2010-01-01',123],['2010-01-02',null],['2010-01-03',349]

I want it to draw a line between 2010-01-01's data and 2010-01-03's data, ignoring 2010-01-02's null value

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without changing the data (or changing the flot source code).

Go through your array with a for loop and remove all datapoints where the value is null.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that. I also added a property to the options of the yaxis named "showNullValues". I then check if this values is set to true, if true I remove the nulls, if false i keep the null values. finally I remove the "showNullValues" property as not to cause any confusion/errors in flot.